# How to print every third line of some text input by user from keyboard?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, user-input

So basically this is the specific question:

Write a Python program that reads input from the keyboard (standard input). The input will consist of some number of lines of text. The input will be terminated by a blank line. Your program should print every third line.

For instance, if the input is the following:

[image: Please see this image!]

Comment: Can you please show your effort? Stack overflow is not a free software writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take input using input() function
and check blank line checking the line is empty string or not

```
i = 1
while 1:
    line = input()
    if line=='':
        break
    if i%3 == 0:
        print(line)
    i = i+1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lines=[]
while True:
   line=input()
   if line=='':
      break
   lines.append(line)
if len(lines)<=2:
   exit()
else:
   print("\n".join(lines[2:len(lines):3]))
```